# date.toISOString is not a function in react-native-date-picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datepicker

I am using below code to pick date time in react native, which uses `react-native-date-picker`:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker;
...
render(){
 return(
    <DatePicker
      mode="datetime"
      date={this.state.date}
      onDateChange={(date)=>{this.setState(date: date)}} />
);}
```

This is the [link](https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker) to the package that I have used. But on using above code, I am getting error `date.toISOString is not a function`. I have used the exact same example as shown in its docs, but it is not working. Also, `react-native-datepicker` isn't working as well.

My React native version>0.60.

Please help me solve the issue.

Here is [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093088/selecting-date-and-time-together-in-react-native/) link to my previous question on same topic and one user suggested me to use `react-native-date-picker`.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue.

It looks like the *react-native-date-picker* package doesn't allow you to use any other date format than the one set inside the package. *You'll have to parse it elsewhere and set its state to the newly parsed value*.

You have two "workarounds" :

1. Use another library datepicker available for react native, there are a lot out there.
2. Download the *date_fns* package (*npm install date_fns --save*). You can use it to easily parse dates and it's lighter than the *moments* package I've seen some people recommend. (You can parse it like this: *formattedDate = format(birthdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');* )

P.S: the example you are refering to is for the "react-native-datepicker" package, and you are using the "react-native-date-picker" package (notice the "-" between "date" and "picker").

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I forgot to add the "date" attribute to the DatePicker component, which is optional.

On iOS this attribute can be omitted and everything will work, but on Android there will be an error: `"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'date.toISOString')".`

The working version of the component looks like this:

```
<DatePicker
   date = {new Date ()}
   mode = {"datetime"}
   onDateChange = {setDate}
   locale = 'en'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try change `date={this.state.date}` to `date={new Date(this.state.date)}`